# Angular2 Router redirects to root Component

Tags: routes, angular

i have implemented/configured an angular2 router, set up the server (asp.net core) to redirect unknown paths to /index.html, and routing seems to work fine, BUT:
When trying to access my site with an specific url (i.e. www.sitename.com/component1/ ) angular always loads it's root-view (www.sitename.com/).

I think that is more or less what it should do, because server requests like '/component1' are being redirected to '/index.html' , but that's not what i want :). 
The way it works now, no user can save bookmarks of child-routes. 
Related to this: when currently at '/component1' route, reloading the page will result in being redirected to the root (/) component as well.

PS: I have set  , as mentioned in several other posts. 
PSS: As mentioned: when navigating through the site via mouse clicks, routing works just fine.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact your server shouldn't redirect to /index.html but serves directly the page without updating the address. I mean as payload of the response...

Redirect actually "redirects" and updates the url... I mean a second request is done with the new url.

So you need to update you server to implement this approach.

Comment: Thank you, changed my server code to "context.Request.Path = "/index.html"      And now it works like it should.  Thank you VERY much!